# Retrieving sentence strings from NLTK corpus

Tags: python, regex, nlp, token, nltk

This is my dataset:

```
emma=gutenberg.sents('austen-emma.txt')
```

It gives me the sentences

```
[[u'she',u'was',u'happy',[u'It',u'was',u'her',u'own',u'good']]
```

But  this is what I want to get:

```
['she was happy','It was her own good']
```

Comment: Is this the right output? Shouldn't it be `[[u'she',u'was',u'happy',], [u'It',u'was',u'her',u'own',u'good']]]`

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be getting correct output, according to the [nltk docs](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html?highlight=sents#nltk.corpus.reader.api.CorpusReader):

> sents(fileids=None)[source]¶
>   Returns:    the given file(s) as a list of sentences or utterances, each encoded as a list of word strings.

So you just need to turn your list of word strings back into a space-separated sentence:

`sentences = [" ".join(list_of_words) for list_of_words in emma]`

Answer (score 3):

As noted by alvas and AShelly, what you see is the correct behavior. However, their approaches of just joining the words of each sentence have two drawbacks:

- You will end up with white-spaces around punctuation (e.g., `"Emma Woodhouse , handsome , clever , and rich , with a comfortable [...]"`).
- You have the `PlaintextCorpusReader` perform sentence tokenization just for reverting it afterwards, which is avoidable computational overhead.

Given the implementation of [`PlaintextCorpusReader`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/plaintext.py), it is easy to derive a function that takes exactly the same steps as `PlaintextCorpusReader.sents()`, but without the sentence tokenization:

```
def sentences_from_corpus(corpus, fileids = None):

    from nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext import read_blankline_block, concat

    def read_sent_block(stream):
        sents = []
        for para in corpus._para_block_reader(stream):
            sents.extend([s.replace('\n', ' ') for s in corpus._sent_tokenizer.tokenize(para)])
        return sents

    return concat([corpus.CorpusView(path, read_sent_block, encoding=enc)
                   for (path, enc, fileid)
                   in corpus.abspaths(fileids, True, True)])
```

In contrast to what I said above, there is one additional step performed by this function: Since we're not doing word tokenization any more, we have to replace newlines with white-spaces.

Passing the `gutenberg` corpus to this function results in:

```
['[Emma by Jane Austen 1816]',
 'VOLUME I',
 'CHAPTER I',
 'Emma Woodhouse, handsome, clever, and rich, with a comfortable home and happy disposition, seemed to unite some of the best blessings of existence; and had lived nearly twenty-one years in the world with very little to distress or vex her.',
 "She was the youngest of the two daughters of a most affectionate, indulgent father; and had, in consequence of her sister's marriage, been mistress of his house from a very early period.",
 ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

The corpora accessed using the `nltk.corpus` API normally returns a document stream, i.e. a list of sentences, each sentence is a list of tokens.

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
>>> emma = gutenberg.sents('austen-emma.txt')
>>> emma[0]
[u'[', u'Emma', u'by', u'Jane', u'Austen', u'1816', u']']
>>> emma[1]
[u'VOLUME', u'I']
>>> emma[2]
[u'CHAPTER', u'I']
>>> emma[3]
[u'Emma', u'Woodhouse', u',', u'handsome', u',', u'clever', u',', u'and', u'rich', u',', u'with', u'a', u'comfortable', u'home', u'and', u'happy', u'disposition', u',', u'seemed', u'to', u'unite', u'some', u'of', u'the', u'best', u'blessings', u'of', u'existence', u';', u'and', u'had', u'lived', u'nearly', u'twenty', u'-', u'one', u'years', u'in', u'the', u'world', u'with', u'very', u'little', u'to', u'distress', u'or', u'vex', u'her', u'.']
```

For the `nltk.corpus.gutenberg` corpus, it loads the `PlaintextCorpusReader`, see
[https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/**init**.py#L114](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/__init__.py#L114)
and https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/plaintext.py

So it's reading a directory of text files, one of which is `'austen-emma.txt'` and it uses the default `sent_tokenize` and `word_tokenize` function to process the corpus. In the code it's instantiated as `tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle` and `WordPunctTokenizer()`, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/plaintext.py#L40

So to get a list of sentence strings as desired, use:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
>>> emma = gutenberg.sents('austen-emma.txt')
>>> sents_list = [" ".join(sent) for sent in emma]
>>> sents_list[0]
u'[ Emma by Jane Austen 1816 ]'
>>> sents_list[1]
u'VOLUME I'
>>> sents_list[:1]
[u'[ Emma by Jane Austen 1816 ]']
>>> sents_list[:2]
[u'[ Emma by Jane Austen 1816 ]', u'VOLUME I']
>>> sents_list[:3]
[u'[ Emma by Jane Austen 1816 ]', u'VOLUME I', u'CHAPTER I']
```